# com.google.gcloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error getting access token for service account:

Tags: google-oauth, google-bigquery, gcloud-java

I am having a program will involves frequently accessing BigQuery using `com.google.gcloud:gcloudjava:0.1.4` with default `BigQueryOptions` configuration

However sometime I am getting error with stacktrace as follows

```
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account:
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:227)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:97)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:74)
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:65)
    at com.google.gcloud.ServiceOptions$1.initialize(ServiceOptions.java:533)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:300)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.gcloud.spi.DefaultBigQueryRpc.query(DefaultBigQueryRpc.java:402)
```

It only failed from time to time, but I am wondering whether there is any way that I could sort of improve the stability of my program. Therefore just in case I am wondering, it is a pure server side problem that I have no way to do about it or is there any way that I could at client side to potentially decrease the possibility of this happening (say by changing the authentication configuration or anything?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a server side problem with google-oauth. I'm having problems with that as well - services that used to work fine can't get an access token anymore (since about 1h).

Comment: https://status.cloud.google.com/ now states "We are investigating an issue with Authentication services. We will provide more information by 07:30 US/Pacific."

Comment: From the status.cloud.google.com RSS feed: The issue with Authentication Services should have been resolved for all affected projects as of 07:24 US/Pacific time.